# ASP.NET Custom WebControl Nested Properties as Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I am trying to implement a Custom Composite WebControl with "nested" properties, i.e., encapsulate a group of properties into a class.

For example, in this composite control, I have placed a button.  I would like to be able to encapsulate relevant properties for the button into a class (e.g., buttonText, buttonStyle, etc.).  This would make defining properties in multi-button/controls composite-control easier and consistent and intuitive.

Note: I would like for the encapsulated properties to appear grouped in the Properties dialog in VisualStudio, in a manner very similar to Style/Font.

Sample:

```
public class fooButtonProperties
{
    [Category("Appearance"), Description("URL for the Profile page")]
    public string URL { get; set; }

    [Category("Appearance"), Description("Text to display"), DefaultValue("Profile")]
    public string ButtonText { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Position of the control on the page, default is Right-Aligned
    /// </summary>
    [Category("Appearance"), Description("Position in the Header"), DefaultValue(PIONEERFramework.Web.UI.WebControls.PageHeaderFooter.Classes.DesignEnum.DesignLayoutEnums.HorizontalPositions.Right)]
///Here is the composite control
    public PIONEERFramework.Web.UI.WebControls.PageHeaderFooter.Classes.DesignEnum.DesignLayoutEnums.HorizontalPositions PositionInHeader { get; set; }
}
public class myCustomClass: System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeControl
{
    protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink myButton;
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public fooButtonProperties myButtonProperties { get { return _profileButtonProp; } }
    private fooButtonProperties _myeButtonProp;

    #region Constructor
    public myCustomClass()
    {
        this._myeButtonProp = new fooButtonProperties ();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach dos not work.  The new property myButtonProperties does not appear at all in the "Properies" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To create a nested property use the `System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute in your control like this:

```
[Category("Appearance")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public fooButtonProperties myButtonProperties { get { return _profileButtonProp; } }
```

The final property name will be "myButtonProperties-URL" (with a hyphen). You can also add this attribute to properties in your `fooButtonProperties` class for even more nesting.
Please note that you may have to close the aspx file and rebuild the solution to refresh the Properties window.

The `Category` attribute works in your control and in your nested class.

The `Description` attribute for the descriptions seems correct BUT it does not work which could be a bug in Visual Studio. I found this link:
https://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653335/webcontrol-property-descriptions-do-not-appear-in-property-window

Also I observed that no properties show descriptions.

Regards
Oli